# ArtScroll Chumash Ashkenazic or Sephardic?

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, translation, pentateuch-chumash

I'd like to know details about these full size one book editions from ArtScroll:

```
Schottenstein Interlinear Chumash Complete in 1 Volume
Stone edition Chumash
```

I know that there are travel size Chumash with a choice either Ashkenazic or Sephardic, but for the full size they don't specify such information.
So the question is: Are the specified books Ashkenazic or Sephardic?

Comment: Be careful. What artscroll calls Sefard is not Sepharadi (Northern Africa) or what the Israelis call edot ha-mizrach. It is a version of Ashkenaz. There is a Sepharadi siddur at artscroll but not what you mention above

Comment: Here is the Sepharadi siddur from artscroll: https://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781422623190.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends what you mean by "Ashkenazic or Sephardic". The travel size chumash is meant to serve both as a chumash and a siddur and so includes Shabbat (and weekday mincha and arvit) prayers in either Ashkenazi or *Sfard* nusach (a chassidic variant of Ashkenazi nusach).

The full size does not include prayers; it's just the chumash itself and haftarot, holiday sections and the five meguillot. Where Ashkenazim and Sephardim read different haftarot, for example, both are included, though there are different traditions for Haftarot for different Sephardic communities and not all communities' traditions are included. Transliteration is hybrid (thank you @Kazi Bacsi) with Ashkenazi consonants and Sephardi vowels) (the parasha for two weeks from now is listed (in the English index) as "Ki Sissa" rather than "Ki Tissa"). Finally, where Ashkenazim and Sephardim sometimes call a given parsha by different names the Ashkenazi name is used.

Comment: Also I think they write פצוע דכה

Comment: ArtScroll's transliteration is hybrid: Ashkenazi consonants with Sefardi vowels.

Comment: They don't include haftarot variants for Yemenite, Tunisian, Italian, etc. Mostly they only include variants they expect you're likely to encounter in an English speaking synagogue.